# I want to append an csv file using python pandas to add an array as new column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have tried the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = {'Names':[1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df_csv = pd.read_csv('try.csv')
df_csv['Names'] = list1
df_csv.to_csv('try.csv', index=False, mode= 'a')
```

The error is as following:

```
"ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"
```

I understand that the size of the dataframe doesn't match but how can I solve that?

So, this is what I want in try.csv file after appending:
[try.csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ru4FS.png)

Comment: So what is your expected out put ....?

Comment: do: `df_csv['Names'] = list1['Names']`

Comment: You can try: `df_csv['Names'] = pd.DataFrame(list1)` instead of `df_csv['Names'] = list1`

Comment: @Wen I already have one column in the try.csv file and I would like to add another one with the data from 'list1'. The number of elements in both the columns are same.

Comment: @YOLO I get the same error again

Comment: @0p3n5ourcE It worked but the all the columns are getting appended at the end of existing columns

Comment: @JankiDesai May be you can try `concat` (*I posted an answer below*).

Comment: @JankiDesai Is it solved?

Comment: @YOLO Yes, both the answers posted below worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, the correct would be:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = {'Names':[1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df_csv = pd.read_csv('try.csv')
df_csv['Names'] = df.Names  # changed here
df_csv.to_csv('try.csv', index=False, mode= 'w')
```

Comment: I get this error: " Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 7, saw 2"

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a dictionary here, whereas your row requires a list of values. You should try this:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = {'Names':[1,2,3,4,5]}

df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
df_csv = pd.read_csv('try.csv')
df_csv['Names'] = list1['Names']
df_csv.to_csv('try.csv', index=False, mode= 'a')
```

Also, it is not clear why would you need an additional df DataFrame for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `concat`. Suppose your `df_csv` has more rows as below then, you can create new dataframe with `list1` and concatenate as new column:

```
import pandas as pd
list1 = {'Names':[1,2,3,4,5]}

# creating dataframe with initial value instead of pd.read_csv
df_csv = pd.DataFrame({'col_1': [100,200,300,400,500,600,700]})
print(df_csv)
```

Result:

```
   col_1
0    100
1    200
2    300
3    400
4    500
5    600
6    700
```

Now, concatenate to `df_csv` with `axis=1` by creating new dataframe with `list1`:

```
list1_df = pd.DataFrame(list1)
# concatenate df_csv and dataframe with list1_df
df_csv = pd.concat([df_csv,list1_df], axis=1)
print(df_csv)
```

Result:

```
   col_1  Names
0    100    1.0
1    200    2.0
2    300    3.0
3    400    4.0
4    500    5.0
5    600    NaN
6    700    NaN
```